# Prove: $f$ is a constant function, as $\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \ \ and \ \ \forall n : \frac{1}{n}$ is a period of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ,  for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$.
Also. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{n}$ is a period of $f$ such that:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \  f(x) = f(x+ \frac{1}{n})$$

**Prove\disprove: $f$ is a constant function.**

my attempt:
I understand that you need to divide the proof for two cases, the first for $x \in \mathbb{R/Q}$ and the other for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I can't understand how to formal this ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply observe that
$$
f(a) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(a+\frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x).$$ Therefore, $f$ is continuous at every $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Observe that by the assumption, it holds that
$$
f(0) = f(\frac{j}{n}),\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N},j\in \mathbb{Z},
$$ and hence that
$$
f(q) = f(0),\quad\forall q\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$ By the continuity of $f$, it follows that
$$f(x) = f(0),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Oops, I misread it. But about $f(a) = f(a=\frac{1}{n})$, it follows directly from the assumption.

Comment: @Rebellos The first equality is obvious from the period 1/n.  Fixing continuous f on a dense set determines the whole function.